# 1.find the largest among each pkey. 2convert a datetime '01-24-2020 10:12:12 am' to 24-Jan-2020

Tags: sql, teradata

1.find the largest date among each pkey

```
PKEY    COL1    COL2    DATE1
1   APPLE1  ORANGE1 01-Jun-20
1   APPLE2  ORANGE2 02-Jun-20
1   APPLE3  ORANGE3 03-Jun-20
1   APPLE4  ORANGE4 04-Jun-20
2   COCONUT1    MANGO1  05-Jun-20
2   COCONUT2    MANGO2  06-Jun-20
2   COCONUT2    MANGO2  07-Jun-20
3   MELON1  LEMON1  08-Jun-20
3   MELON2  LEMON2  09-Jun-20
3   MELON3  LEMON3  10-Jun-20
3   MELON4  LEMON4  11-Jun-20
4   WALNUT1 HAZELNUT1   12-Jun-20
4   WALNUT2 HAZELNUT2   13-Jun-20
4   WALNUT3 HAZELNUT3   14-Jun-20
```

2. convert a datetime '01-24-2020 10:12:12 am' to 24-Jan-2020

Comment: Start by converting your dates to date datatype.(str_to_date)

Comment: what have you tried so far? share your code.

Comment: This is a totally different question after edit.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:
Note that the concept of rank is being used.

```
SET @intRank := 1;
SET @intPrevPKEY := -1;

SELECT PKEY, COL1, COL2, DATE1
FROM
(
    SELECT *, 
    IF(@intPrevPKEY = PKEY, @intRank := @intRank + 1, @intRank :=1) AS rank,
    @intPrevPkey := PKEY
    FROM your_table
    ORDER BY PKEY, STR_TO_DATE(DATE1, '%d-%M-%y') DESC
) AS inner_table
WHERE inner_table.rank = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

This simple query should work.

```
Select pkey,max(STR_TO_DATE(DATE1, '%d-%M-%y')) as MAX_DATE from  TABLE_NAME group by pkey;
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that *largest date among each pkey* does not mean a simple MAX and you want the **row** with the largest date:

```
select *
from tab
qualify 
   rank() 
   over (partition by PKEY
         order by DATE1 desc) = 1
```

For casting a string to datetime you can apply qa FORMAT:

```
cast(cast(col as timestamp format 'mm-dd-yyyyBhh:mi:ssBt') as date)
```